# How to prevent installation of package with newer version than requested?

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, software-installation, updates

I am installing a package called `nvhpc` from a third party repository.

To do that I use the recommended method that consists on:

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y --quiet ca-certificates
$ echo 'deb [trusted=yes] https://developer.download.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/ubuntu/amd64 /'
$ apt-get update -y
$ apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y  nvhpc-22-2
```

It turns out that this tries to install `nvhpc-22-3` which is a newer version.
(I don't want to install it because, among other things, I don't have space in my virtual machine for both version).

It is also strange that if I install explicitly `nvhpc-22-3` (or `nvhpc`) it install only version 22.3, while if I ask for `nvhpc-22-2` it will install both 22.2 and 22.3.
(22.3 or 22.2 alone should fit in the disk.)

I think the repository or `apt-get` is trying to be smart and installing old and new versions.
**How can I prevent the installation of the newer version?** (that is, the package specifically called `nvhpc-22-3` or `nvhpc`)?

Note that I pass the argument `--no-install-recommends` to prevent things like that, in case that is related.

This is the output for the last command above:

```
$ apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y  nvhpc-22-2
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
nvhpc-22-2 nvhpc-22-3 perl ...
...
0 upgraded, 98 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 5909 MB of archives.
After this operation, 20.5 GB of additional disk space will be used.
...
Selecting previously unselected package nvhpc-22-3.
Preparing to unpack .../94-nvhpc-22-3_22.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvhpc-22-3 (22.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvhpc-2022.
Preparing to unpack .../95-nvhpc-2022_22.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvhpc-2022 (22.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvhpc-22-2.
Preparing to unpack .../96-nvhpc-22-2_22.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvhpc-22-2 (22.2) ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a version issue. These are actually two different packages, not two different versions of the same package. It appears that `nvhpc-22-3` is a dependency of `nvhpc-22-2`.

For whatever reason, they made it a dependency so you are going to have to install both packages. Most likely, `nvhpc-22-2` is not complete and `nvhpc-22-3` contains some stuff needed for `nvhpc-22-2` to be complete.

In any case, each of these has a different name so questions about version number are irrelevant (you can't use typical methods of apt pinning to a specific version). You can contact the vendor if you don't feel this is necessary or if you want to find out why it is necessary.

You can verify this by running:

```
apt-cache show nvhpc-22-2 | grep -i depends
```

and this should show that `nvhpc-22-3` is a dependency. Apt is not intelligent beyond dependency issues and will not try to install packages that aren't dependencies, particularly when you use the `--no-install-recommends` flag.

Lastly, if you feel this is a bug, you can also file a bug report with the software vendor.

Comment: The only other situation I can think of would be if `nvhpc-22-3` were a dependency of a dependency of `nvhpc-22-2`.

Comment: To check if `nvhpc-22-3` is a dependency of a dependency of `nvhpc-22-2`, you could run `for i in $(apt-cache show nvhpc-22-2 | grep -i depends | grep -Po ' [a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9] '); do echo $i; apt-cache show $i | grep -i depends; done`

Comment: I see, so this is probably a defect or a workaround (on their side) on how dependencies are specified in the repository. I tried with `nvhpc-22-1` and it also depends on `nvhpc-22-3`. I guess I can force not to install dependencies but then things may not work.

Comment: hehe, things are getting worst ! now `nvhpc-22-3` depends on `nvhpc-22-5`. So among other things installing 22.3 requires more than twice the size.

Comment: @alfC I would file a bug with Nvidia about the issue. Having individual packages rely on shared dependencies should result in less disk space, not more. It shouldn't require newer versions if the dependencies aren't necessary. This might just be a bug.

Comment: @alfC Quick question, do you have a package named `nvhpc` installed *with no version number in the name*? If so, this is probably a metapackage and I would assume it's safe to uninstall. This metapackage would require the newest version as a dependency, similar to the kernel packages for Ubuntu.

Comment: @alfC However, I guess that if `apt-cache show nvhpc-22-2 | grep -i depends` shows `nvhpc-22-3` as a dependency, then this isn't the case and it won't solve the issue.